# Flatten a list of lists in Python Flatten() does not work Possible generator issue

Tags: python, list, generator, flatten

I believe I have an issue with generators, and I am not sure if it is my code or possibly something to do with my coding environment (I am using a Jupyter Notebook)

Desired result:

I wish to turn this list of lists:

`ugh = [["hi","this"], ["is","annoying"], ["like...","really"], ["reallly","annoying"]]`

Into a list of strings, like this:

`["hi","this","is","annoying","like...","really","reallly","annoying"]`

I've so far tried using both `itertools.chain` and variations of `flatten()` and so far my results have been the below:

Flatten Function:

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(coll):
    for i in coll:
            if isinstance(i, Iterable) and not isinstance(i, basestring):
                for subc in flatten(i):
                    yield subc
            else:
                yield i

print(flatten(ugh))
```

result: <generator object flatten at 0x7f8ccf3c6250>

Itertools:

```
print(list(itertools.chain(*sublist)) for sublist in ugh)
```

result: <generator object  at 0x7f8ccf3c6250>

I would really appreciate help with this, as when I search up either output, I get no results.

Comment: That function is actually fine you just need to consume the generator: `list(flatten(ugh))`, or `for elem in flatten(ugh):`.

Comment: One should always prefer list comprehensions as they are optimized and often much faster and efficient than iterations and loops. I have given one line of code below to get what you were expecting as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
ugh = [["hi","this"], ["is","annoying"], ["like...","really"], ["reallly","annoying"]];
ugh = np.array(ugh);
flatten_ugh = ugh.flatten();
print(flatten_ugh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to upack and often much faster and efficient also - is to use list comprehension. I have used a nested one as there was a list within a list.

```
[val for sublist in ugh for val in sublist]
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: True for deeper levels like - list of lists of lists, then you will have to go deeper in list comprehension as well. Would be mind-splitting. I find 2 levels deep list comprehension heavy on brain allready !.